# iOS: Why does hidden button still receive tap events?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, storyboard

According to the Apple docs, hidden `UIButtons` should not receive tap events.

However, our app has a `UIButton` receiving tap events despite being hidden.

This function is the `IB Action` invoked when the button is tapped. When the button is removed from Storyboard, this function doesn't get invoked. When the button is added to Storyboard, the function gets invoked -- even though the button is hidden.

To verify that the button is hidden, we put a breakpoint inside the function and ran `expr sender.hidden` from the Xcode debugger. The result: true.

The stack trace shows the IB Action is triggered by code in UIApplicationMain, not our code.

Through the Connections Inspector, we confirmed there is no other trigger for the IB Action except the mysterious button.

Thoroughly confused. Suggestions?

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {        
    // If here, handle tap
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you programmatically triggering the button tap in any way?

Comment: you can set userInteractionEnable = false when button is hidden

Comment: @Watson nope not programmatically triggering the button.

Comment: You can check in simulator view hierarchy if your IBAction is is being referenced by another UIObject or button

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan userInteractionEnable should not be needed. According to the Apple docs, hidden UIButtons should not receive gesture events.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan correct. It is not.

Comment: Wait wait...have you make all this test by clearing the cache and on a real device? 
We do not reach hasty conclusions..

Comment: Yes, this is running on a real device. Will try cleaning the build to see if that matters. Is that what you meant by clearing the cache?

Comment: I mean shift+alt+cmd+k (clean the build folder..) and delete derived data from project tab

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano ok will try that

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano did not work :(

Comment: @Crashlot Ok, seems a problem of times. When you change your hidden status? Can you post some code? I want try to help you, maybe there is an explaination

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano thanks for the help. As mentioned, if the UIButton is removed from Storyboard, that simple change ensures the IB Action is not invoked. So it has something to do with the UIButton. There is nothing in code that triggers the IB Action, which is proved when we put a breakpoint inside the IB Action, which shows the IB Action is caused by something in UIApplicationMain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an incomplete UIButton extension that didn't account for visibility in determining hit tests.

This function correctly handles the case where UIButtons are hidden.

```
extension UIButton {
    public override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // Ignore if button hidden
        if self.hidden {
            return nil
        }

        // If here, button visible so expand hit area
        let hitSize = CGFloat(56.0)
        let buttonSize = self.frame.size
        let widthToAdd = (hitSize - buttonSize.width > 0) ? hitSize - buttonSize.width : 0
        let heightToAdd = (hitSize - buttonSize.height > 0) ? hitSize - buttonSize.height : 0
        let largerFrame = CGRect(x: 0-(widthToAdd/2), y: 0-(heightToAdd/2), width: buttonSize.width+widthToAdd, height: buttonSize.height+heightToAdd)
        return (CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point)) ? self : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set enable = false like this:

```
button.enabled = false
```

For Swift 3 would be:

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

A situation I encountered was that I was toggling between two different buttons based on application state. When I created the second of these two buttons, I copied and pasted the first. This also copied the first button's outlets.

I thought that the first button was being pressed when only the second button was showing, but in reality the second button was sending events to both the outlet I intended AND the one that was set when I copied the first button.

To determine if this is the case in your situation, go to the interface builder, select your button, and check that the touch events are set up exactly how you want in the connections inspector. If any of the connections are wrong, you can remove them by clicking the little 'x'.